# Use json_array_elements(json) and get item ranks

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a json made of two levels of arrays like :

```
[
  {
    name: "Group one",
    races: 
    [
     {name: "Race 1"},
     {name: "Race 2"},
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Group two",
    races: 
    [
     {name: "Race 10"},
     {name: "Race 11"},
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to get by magic SQL :

```
group_num | race_num | race
int       | int      | json
1         | 1        | {name: "Race 1"}
1         | 2        | {name: "Race 2"}
2         | 1        | {name: "Race 10"}
2         | 2        | {name: "Race 11"}
```

in which :

- `group_num` is the rank of each group in its array
- `race_num` is the rank of each race in its array

I presume this could have something to do with `json_array_elements(json)` and `row_number() OVER ()` but I can't figure how to make it right !

Comment: How do you run SQL on JSON? or from where did you get that JSON? did you run an existing query to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with my_table(data) as (
values(
'[
  {
    "name": "Group one",
    "races": 
    [
     {"name": "Race 1"},
     {"name": "Race 2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Group two",
    "races": 
    [
     {"name": "Race 10"},
     {"name": "Race 11"}
    ]
  }
]'::json)
)
select 
    group_num, 
    rank() over (partition by group_num order by value->>'name') as race_num,
    value as race
from (
    select 
        rank() over (order by value->>'name') as group_num, 
        value as grp
    from my_table,
    json_array_elements(data)
    ) s,
json_array_elements(grp->'races');
```

Results:

```
 group_num | race_num |        race         
-----------+----------+---------------------
         1 |        1 | {"name": "Race 1"}
         1 |        2 | {"name": "Race 2"}
         2 |        1 | {"name": "Race 10"}
         2 |        2 | {"name": "Race 11"}
(4 rows)
```

Note, your json is invalid, use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate json expressions.